# Fill List based on condition

Tags: c#, list, vector-graphics

Is there a faster way to fill a list based on a function like distance for vectors?

```
private static IEnumerable<Vector2> SortSpecialBuildingsByDistance(
     Vector2 house, 
     IEnumerable<Vector2> specialBuildings)
{
    List<float> optionList = new List<float>();
    foreach (var item in specialBuildings)
    {
        optionList.Add(Vector2.Distance(item, house));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use Linq to get it down to one line, but it wouldn't be faster.  On a side note your code wouldn't even compile since it doesn't have a return.

Comment: Yes i know this is only a part of the method! I prefer a one liner compared to this code

Comment: I'm not sure using anything parallel in adding to a shared list will actually cause you to gain any performance. Everything you do, measure first, then decide. BTW, I don't see you filtering anything, only adding distance to a list.

Comment: Oher direction you may look for faster solution is: math (find optimal way to achieve your goal, and may be not compute distance at all, or compute only a few of them), datastructure/code organization (may be you do not need them sorted, may be you do not really need distance notion, may be something else..) I just speculate without really knowing much about your project. But those are places where you get *really* performance boost, as usual.

Comment: As mentioned, the optimization is probably not in the code but in the math. I presume `Vector2.Distance` takes a square root... if you want to make things faster, you should store the square of the distance (after all, `x^2 < y^2` if and only if `x < y`, for non-negative `x` and `y`).

Comment: I have a list of buildings (specialbuildings) which all get their distance compared to 1 building (house) , this list will be merge sorted after their distance is calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing *PLinq* (*Parallel* Linq):

```
  List<float> optionList = specialBuildings
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(item => Vector2.Distance(item, house))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Parallel.ForEach:

```
ConcurrentBag<Vector2> optionList = new ConcurrentBag<Vector2>();
Parallel.ForEach(specialBuildings, (item) => { optionList.Add(Vector2.Distance(item, house)); });
```

List is not thread-safe so you will need to use one of the [Thread-Safe Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx). The above example uses ConcurrentBag but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

The code may not run faster, but you could do it in one line:
`return specialBuildings.Select(item => Vector2.Distance(item, house)).ToList()`